# Scanning JSON data in different parent

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a external JSON file and phrase it to a local object array with structure like the following code

```
{
  "post": {
     "sample": {
       "state": "neutral"
     },
     "demo": {
       "state": "positive"
     }
  }
}
```

How can I get all the value of `state` in all parent and save it (save to a array) or print it out (`console.log`)

I want to have a result like `["neutral", "positive"]`

#### Node.js or JS solution are all welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with iterating all properties and check if one key is `state`, then collect the value. If the property is an object, then collect from the property the states with a recursion.

```js
function getStates(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) {
        if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            return r.concat(getStates(o[k]));
        }
        if (k === 'state') {
            r.push(o.state);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var object = { post: { sample: { state: "neutral" }, demo: { state: "positive" } } };

console.log(getStates(object));
```

For a variable use of a dynamic key, you could use another parameter for it. This means, you need to insert the key for every repeated call.

```js
function getStates(o, label) {
    return Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) {
        if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            return r.concat(getStates(o[k], label));
            //                              ^^^^^    call with label
        }
        if (k === label) {
            r.push(o[label]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var object = { post: { sample: { state: "neutral" }, demo: { state: "positive" } } };

console.log(getStates(object, 'state'));
```

For getting the parent, you could store the path to the value and take it as value.

```js
function getStates(o, p, q) {
    p = p || [],
    q = q || {};
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        var t = p.concat(k);
        if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            getStates(o[k], t, q);
            return;
        }
        q[o.state] = t.join('.');
    });
    return q;
}

var object = { post: { sample: { state: "neutral" }, demo: { state: "positive" } } };

console.log(getStates(object));
```

Comment: Excuse me, I have modify the code to a function that you can use with other  string not only state but it doesn't work, what's wrong? [here is my code](https://files.andrewyg.net/code/712.js)

Comment: @AndrewYoung, you need to hand over `label` as well inside of the function for another call. please see edit.

Comment: Hi, can we extend this function to also return their parent? e.g. {"neutral": "object.post.sample.state", "positive": "object.post.demo.state"}

Comment: @AndrewYoung, you need another function with keeping the path to the value for the object.

Answer (score 1):

If your json structure will always be the same you can use the following snippet

```js
let obj = {
  "post": {
     "sample": {
       "state": "neutral"
     },
     "demo": {
       "state": "positive"
     }
  }
};

for(let p in obj.post){
   console.log(obj.post[p].state)
}
```

Comment: I like your code since your code is cleaner but I have discovered on thing that I may lost in my question how if I also want to get the `state` under `page` and `page` is the toppest value not under the `post` so I remove all the `.post` but it doesn't work, Also your code looks like it's build on the base if all the object under `post` have a `state` value. If you can give me a answer with above requirement I think I can give you the most useful question. But your answer is acceptable since I didn't tell the full condition.

Comment: @Andrewyg that's why i wrote in my answer that my code will only work if your json structure is always the same. If that's not the case then Nina's answer is better.

Comment: OK, I consider your code for first glance since it's cleaner!!! Nice code, but only fit in some situation